# Getting closest point-feature of another point-feature

Tags: gdal, shapefile, point, saga, proximity

I have two point-shapefiles. For each point-feature in one of those two files I want to identify the closest point-feature from the other file and save the `"ID"` of this point as attribute. Is there any way to do this in SAGA or GDAL?

e.g. point `"A"` (from the first shp) is closest to point `"11"` (from the second shp) -> point `"A"` gets the value `"11"` in its attribute table.

Comment: In SAGA there are some modules [Snap Points to Points](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.2/shapes_points_18.html) and [Point Distances](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.2/shapes_points_3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it, but I think it's unnecessarily complicated:

1. I used "snap points to points" (`saga_cmd shapes_points 18`) @Taras suggested, to snap one of my layers to the other one.
2. Then, since I am not aware of SAGA having a spatial join tool, I created small buffers around the points which stayed at their location with `saga_cmd shapes_tools 18`.
3. Afterwards, I added the polygon attributes to the snapped points with `saga_cmd shapes_points 10`.
4. Then, I joined the original not-snapped points onto the snapped points with now additional information with `saga_cmd table_tools 3`.

This takes way too long for the big areas which need to be analysed. So further suggestions are welcome. I feel like there must be a faster way.